# Что лучше использовать for...of или Array.prototype.forEach()?

Tags: javascript

Нужно сделать обход массива.

И стоит ли писать так `[1,2,3].forEach(async function(e){console.log(e);});` ?

Или стоит писать так `for (let e of [1,2,3]) {console.log(e);}` ?

Аж от всего многообразия глаза разбегаются. Разницы не вижу. Хотелось бы более быстрого выполнения кода.

Comment: `Хотелось бы более быстрого выполнения кода` - на массивах в миллиард элементов может и будет разница.... но на маленьких, которые используют во фронтенде - без разницы

Comment: Это более вопрос стиля кода чем производительности, если функция короткая (1 операция например) я часто пишу первым образом. Если длинная то пишу через цикл.

Comment: ну типа такого `regexpData.forEach(async function(e){if( e.test(str) ) console.log(e.exec(str));});` (str = let переменой в верхнем блоке) легко разобрать вам что к чему

Comment: Ну самый быстрый способ будет - обход через индексы, как обычно `for(let i=0;i<arr.length;i++){console.log(arr[i]);}`.

Answer (score 2):

Самый быстрый способ - обход по индексу.

Пример на [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/csofvppz/1/).

```js
function fillArray(cnt) {
  let res = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
    res.push(i);
  }
  return res;
}

var arr = fillArray(5000000);

var t = null;

t = Date.now();
arr.forEach(async function(e, i) {
  arr[i] += 1;
});
console.log('time forEach async', Date.now() - t);

t = Date.now();
arr.forEach(function(e, i) {
  arr[i] += 1;
});
console.log('time forEach', Date.now() - t);

t = Date.now();
for (let e of arr) {
  e += 1; // здесь мы значение массива не меняем
}
console.log('time let of', Date.now() - t);

t = Date.now();
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  arr[i] += 1;
}
console.log('time for with index', Date.now() - t);
```

### Update

На самом деле тест получился довольно спорным, потому что в цикле мы меняем массив, а эта операция может иметь разное время выполнения в плане скорости.

Поэтому, было бы логичнее запускать пустой цикл, без действий внутри.

Как указал в комментариях @Grundy, в **Edge** быстрее.

Пример на пустом цикле [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/csofvppz/4/).

```js
function fillArray(cnt) {
  let res = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
    res.push(i);
  }
  return res;
}

var arr = fillArray(5000000);

var t = null;

t = Date.now();
arr.forEach(function(e, i) {

});
console.log('time forEach', Date.now() - t);

t = Date.now();
for (let e of arr) {

}
console.log('time let of', Date.now() - t);

t = Date.now();
var len = arr.length;
for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {

}
console.log('time for with index', Date.now() - t);
```

Самое интересное проверять результаты в **Edge**.

В представленном выше коде даже в **Edge** обход по индексу получается быстрее.

Но есть 3 интересных нюанса:

- если мы уберем переменную `let len = arr.length;`, код станет работать медленее.
- если мы заменени `let i = 0` на `var i = 0`, код станет работать медленее.
- если мы добавим во все циклы код изменения массива, обход по индексу станет медленнее.

Думаю, можно сделать вывод, что в **Edge** плохая оптимизация кода.

Comment: ееее!!! болел за for. старички показали этим новым фичам.

Comment: Годно, правда я думал, что оба форика будут работать примерно с одной скоростью. А потом вспомнил, что это же не компилируемый язык. Однако в зависимости от браузера/платформы все же может немного скакать

Comment: Вообще у вас тест неправильный. В for тоже надо вызывать функцию, а вы просто обращаетесь к элементу массива! Вот правильный тест: https://jsperf.com/for-vs-foreach-vs-for-of2

Comment: Кстати, с этим тестом. У меня браузер выдает `178 51 13 10` соответственно, а `node.js` `172 51 12 14`, так что по индексу быстрее лишь условно... Нода и хром последние. **P.S.** прогнал на ноде несколько раз, на ноде очень сильно скачет. `+- 5` для каждого из четырех тестов, при том для каждого независимо.

Comment: @Hipster надеюсь, это был сарказм с вашей стороны. Зачем мне вызывать функцию в `for`?

Comment: @selya естественно, для разных платформ и браузеров результаты будут отличаться)

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko имелось в виду вызывать функцию `console.log()`, так как в вопросе именно ее вызывает автор в цикле. Вот. А что касается разных платформ - я лишь сделал тесты и написал это потому, что у вас в ответе написано `самый быстрый способ - обход по индексу`. Я лишь написал, что это не совсем (не всегда) верно. Вот

Comment: Почему-то у меня forEach быстрее. Ох уж это JS с его одним потоком. А почему не используете `console.time(); console.timeEnd();` ? Одно из теста понял, то что forEach с async function писать не стоит. Думаю буду склоняться к for...of хоть он и медленнее в некоторых случаях.

Comment: @АлексТвояТруба Интересно, в каком браузере у вас `forEach` быстрее. Подозреваю, что это мозила. В браузерах хром, edge, и сафари `for` быстрее.

Comment: @selya очень страшно было вызывать `console.log` 5 миллионов раз) И я не думаю, что автор хочет делать именно `console.log` в цикле, поэтому делал хоть какую-то полезную работу)

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko вы правы мозила. `console.log` используется наподобие маркера, что у нас все в порядке и переменные имеют нужное значение -но думаю и так все это знают. Если кому интересно мне массив нужен для хранения RegExp, а то URLSearchParams не справляется с аргументами если у них разный регистр `.getAll("hell") != .getAll("Hell)"`

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, в edge и ie `forEach` выполняется быстрее обычного for

Comment: @Grundy на самом деле - зависит от нескольких факторов. Посмотрите, я обновил ответ.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, ну либо, все проще, и результаты тестов показывают не то, что ты ожидаешь :-)

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko _логичнее запускать пустой цикл, без действий внутри._ - на самом деле нет, так как пустой цикл может быть вообще выкинут при выполнении

Comment: @Grundy На самом деле таки да. Потому что от того, что мы делаем внутри цикла - зависит его скорость, разумеется. А быстродействие этих действий может зависить от движка. И также мы по результатам теста видно, что цикл все-таки прогоняется.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, видно, что _что-то_ делается, но ты не можешь гарантировать, что это именно цикл

Comment: @Grundy Цикл шредингера)) Мы знаем, что цикл есть. Но не знаем, работает он или нет. Как только мы попытаемя узнать, работает ли он, он точно начинает работать! Или цикл суперпозиции почти))

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, нужно смотреть во что это в итоге собралось, что опять же от движка зависит

Answer (score 0):

ИМХО лучше использовать просто `for` и с точки зрения читаемости, и с точки зрения производительности https://jsperf.com/for-vs-foreach-vs-for-of2